# SharePoint 2016 Online : SharePoint library file uploading issue. Error : Ensurer was not managed across thread transitions

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload, sharepoint-library

While i am trying to upload any file in the SharePoint library (in SharePoint Online). It gives me an error "Ensurer was not managed across thread transitions". Not able to figured it out why it's happening. Please help somebody to fix this issue. I am facing this issue since last 3 hours. Before that everything is working fine.

Here is the snapshot of an error
[image: Error Snapshot]

Comment: Since morning I am also facing the same error while uploading any document.
Kindly help somebody to fix this issue. Vikram Joshi

Comment: Yes vikram. The issue was facing by all users and it is mainly for SharePoint modern UI. And after 5-6 hours it was fixed for Modern UI too by SharePoint Portal Team.
Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below steps:

- Open the SharePoint URL link in IE (internet explorer)
- Go to bottom left and click on the link "Return to classic
  SharePoint" (as shown below)

[image]

Now you will able to upload file (issue is related to SharePoint modern UI).

The same approach can be used if facing issue while uploading on "OneDrive".

Comment: thanks vikas.
The issue was also resolved by default after 5-6 hours for SharePoint modern UI too by SharePoint Team.